# How to clear a form using formik - react native

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, formik

I'm using formik on my react native app, and I having an issue when the user clicks next, I want to clear the form,. on the documentation it said to use resetform(). But on my form this is no doing anything it doesn't clear the form.

Is there a way to clear the form or reset the page.

```
<Formik 
    initialValues = {{fname: '', lname:'' }}
    onSubmit = {async (values, {setSubmitting, resetForm}) => {
        resetForm({ values: (values.fname = '', values.lname ='')})
        
    }}
    >
    {({handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, isSubmitting, resetForm}) => ( 
        <> 
            <View style={styles.style2}>
                
                <View style={styles.Form}>
                    
                    <MyTextInput
                        label           = "First Name" 
                        onChangeText    = {handleChange('fname')}
                        onBlur          = {handleBlur('fname')}
                        values          = {values.fname || ''}
                        returnKeyType   = "next"
                        innerRef={input1}
                        onSubmitEditing = {() => input2.current.focus()}
                    />
                    <MyTextInput
                        label           = "Last Name" 
                        onChangeText    = {handleChange('lname')}
                        onBlur          = {handleBlur('lname')}
                        values          = {values.lname}
                        returnKeyType   = "next"
                        refInner        = {input2} 
                    /> 
                </View> 

            </View>
            <View style={styles.ButtonsStyles}>
                
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.StyleButton} onPress={handleSubmit} activeOpacity={0.85}>
                    <Text style={styles.Link}>
                        Next  ></Octicons>
                    </Text>  
                </TouchableOpacity>
                

            </View>

        </>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: what happens when you just do resetForm() ? Also did you check whether you are able to get into the onSubmit function ?

Comment: @Shyam NOthing happends when I get back to the form page the inputs still have the previous values.

Comment: okay , can you confirm whether clicking on `next` calls your onSubmit ? . Can you add a console log inside your onSubmit --> fill all the form values and hit next . Check whether the log is getting printed .

Comment: @Shyam mmh look like it resets the vlaues but doesn't clear the inputs text :/